# How to make a function if ADX is moving up or down

Tags: pine-script

I'm a very novice pine-script programmer, but trying to do this:

If `ADX(10,10)` changes direction then `SellLong`

```
SellLong = ChangeDirection(ADX(10,10))
```

Although `ChangeDirection` doesn't seem to be a function. Is `ADX` a built-in function?
Can someone assist on this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

ADX is comprised in the [dmi()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_dmi) function.
This function returns 3 values:

- Positive Directional Movement (+DI)
- Negative Directional Movement (-DI)
- Average Directional Movement Index (ADX)

This is what you need:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

[di_pos, di_neg, adx] = dmi(10, 10)

SellLong = change(adx) > 0 ? true : false

plot(SellLong ? 1 : 0)
```